# How do I get this php foreach to parse through all of the <mod> entries?

Tags: php, xml, minecraft

I need to parse the "name" and "version" attributes from all of the "<mod>" tag entries.

Thanks to [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp) I was only able to parse the first "<mod>" tag from the xml.

I'm no programmer, so I have no clue how to go on.

This is my [xml file](https://hastebin.com/mavasavene.xml).

These are my testing php files.

```
$xmlfile = simplexml_load_file("packa.xml");
foreach ($xmlfile->children() as $mods) {
    echo $mods->mod['name']."</br>";
    echo $mods->mod['version'];
}
```

had this output.

```
</br></br>Just Enough Items</br>4.15.0.293
```

And

```
foreach ($xmlfile->children() as $mods) {
    echo $mods->mod['name']."
    </br>".$mods->mod['version'];
}
```

had this output

```
</br>
</br>Just Enough Items
</br>4.15.0.293
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong level in the XML in the `foreach()` loop, this is only looping over the `<mods>` elements - and there is only 1.  You need to specify that you want to loop over the `<mod>` elements and then just access the attributes as you already do...

```
foreach ($xmlfile->mods->mod as $mod) {
    echo $mod['name'] . "/" . $mod['version'] . "</br>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something along these lines, using xpath:

```
$result = $xmlfile->xpath('//mods//mod');  
foreach($result as $mod){
    $nam = $mod->xpath('.//@name');
    $ver = $mod->xpath('.//@version');
    echo implode ( $nam). "</br>" .implode( $ver );  
    echo "<br>";   
}
```

Output:

```
Just Enough Items
4.15.0.293
MTLib
3.0.6
CraftTweaker2
1.12-4.1.20
Mod Tweaker
4.0.18
```

etc.